# Pulling data from Excel file within Fortran

Tags: excel, fortran

I have an Excel sheet with 8000 data points (Column A). Every row from 0 to 8000 have different corresponding values in column B, C etc.

I need to write a Fortran code that should sense the input, compare it with Column A and should give an output from Column B of the same row.

I have exported the Excel file into PRN format and Just to get an idea, I'm testing the following code example and get en error:

```
Error 52, invalid character in field at line 10_
```

(See the Attached photo, [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbNyX.jpg)). Any suggestion which character is invalid? I'm writing in Plato IDE

```
!FTN95 application...

program FreeFormat

real*4, dimension(5) :: Open, High, Low, Close, DayAverage
real*4 :: average

open(unit=1, file='C:\Users\MUHAMMADARSLAN\Desktop\Fortran Test\Table.prn',   status='old')
do i=1,5
read(1,*)Open(i), High(i), Low(i), Close(i), DayAverage(i)
enddo
average = sum(DayAverage)/5
write(*,'("Average is",f5.2)')average

end program FreeFormat
```

Text inside the `Table.prn` file:

Open    70
High    50
Low     10
Close   5
DayAverage  100
All values are separated by a `Tab`, from their variable names.

Comment: Welcome back.  *any suggestion which character is invalid?*  Well, one of the characters in the 10th line of the input file.  I suggest you cut and paste the first 12 lines from your input file and add them to the question.  Without that we'd just be guessing.  My guess is that the 10th line contains something which is not a digit, not a `.` and not whitespace.

Comment: Error is not from the input file, it's from the `FORTRAN` application's 10th line. The 10th line is the one starting with `read` ; `read(1,*)Open(i), High(i), Low(i), Close(i), DayAverage(i)` @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: I think High Performance Mark is right and the error is in the input file, unless it is some character that got lost during copying the code here. The status can be find in any manual and in many questions here. It says the file being opened must already exist.

Comment: The code is exactly the same and to show you all, I had an image attached. There might be something wrong with the `Table.prn` file. @VladimirF

Comment: I'm not sure if you well understood the question. Line 10 which I have mentioned multiple times, is concerned with the input file (`Table.prn`) and it is obvious that the error comes while reading the file; error in `Table.prn` file or the text character error from the line 10.

Comment: Arsalan, Mark said that in the very first comment and you said he is wrong. He is experienced so much that he has no problem understanding these simple questions. I think it is the time to show us the input file Table.prn.

Comment: Yes, I said that and It seems like that. Otherwise I would have got an error concerning the file I'm reading the data from. I appereciate the time of all of you guys but the way he reflected made me feel bad. Sure I can show you the file. Should I include a photo?  @VladimirF

Comment: you are getting an error concerning the file. you could use a `status=` flag on the `read` since your compiler gives such a useless error message maybe it will tell you something.

Comment: a bit of an aside, (maybe), but why save data as csv and give a prn extension?

Comment: Oh, it's a mistake. I initially tried with `CSV` and forgot to update the question. Thanks for pointing out @agentp

Comment: But you ARE getting an error concerning the file! You **really** should show us the file. I am sure it is not compatible with your code. I would add an `iostat=` specifier to the read statement.

Comment: I have updated the question with the text of the `Table.prn` file. Please check @VladimirF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is completely incompatible with how you are reading it.

The command

```
do i=1,5
  read(1,*)Open(i), High(i), Low(i), Close(i), DayAverage(i)
enddo
```

expects 5 lines and 5 numbers on each line. There should be no text strings there. The numbers can be on more lines, but definitely there should be 25 numbers in total and no text in between.

Depending on what is the primary thing you have to change the code or the input file.

Comment: What do I need to write in between the 5 numbers on the same line; `komma` , `fullstop` or a `Tab` ?

Comment: Best is a space. A comma will work too. Read about *list-directed format* in your favourite textbook, manual or search this site.

Comment: Thanks man. It has finally worked :-) But without the text string, how can I read the file with 8000 `rows` and 4 data points in every row? My actual idea is receiving an input, comparing it with the first column data entries, and pulling the data from column 2 or 3 of the matched row (with the input received), for example. @Vladimir F

Comment: You should first study more about reading files in Fortran and about using format descriptors. Seriously, it is too complex to treat in a simple answer. Sometimes one must open a textbook and learn something.